# Converting an igraph.vs object into a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, igraph

So I am using all_shortest_paths to get an output, which looks like this:

```
library(igraph)

PathsE

$res[[1]]
+ 4/990 vertices, named:
[1] Sortilin  GGA1      Ubiquitin PIMT     

$res[[2]]
+ 4/990 vertices, named:
[1] Sortilin TrkA     PLK1     PIMT    

$res[[3]]
+ 4/990 vertices, named:
[1] Sortilin APP      JAB1     PIMT
```

I would like to turn this into a dataframe so that I can manipulate it.
For reference, I would like the dataframe to look like this:

```
                  Prot1      Prot2   Prot3   Prot4
         Pathway1 Sortilin   GGA1    PLK1    PIMT
         Pathway2 Sortilin   TrkA    PLK1    PIMT 
         Pathway3 Sortilin   APP     JAB1    PIMT
```

*I know how to change the axes names
I have tried

```
PathsDF<-as.data.frame(PathsE)
```

but I get this error:

> Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) :
> cannot coerce class ""igraph.vs"" to a data.frame

I also tried this:

```
PathDF <- as.data.frame(get.edgelist(PathsE))
```

but I get this error

> Error in get.edgelist(PathsE) : Not a graph object

When I examine the data strture using `class` and `str`

```
class(PathsEF)
[1] "list"

str(PathsE)
..$ :Class 'igraph.vs'  atomic [1:4] 338 204 40 913
.. .. ..- attr(*, "env")=<weakref>
.. .. ..- attr(*, "graph")= chr "717e99fb-b7db-4e35-8fd3-1d8d741e6612" 
etc
```

which looks like a matrix to me.

From this information, do any of you have any ideas about how to convert this into a dataframe.  I am sorry if I am missing anything obvious- I am pretty new to R!

Comment: What do you want your data frame to look like?

Comment: Please see my edits!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, a couple of clarifying points. The object created by `all_shortest_paths` is a list with two elements: 1) `res` and 2) `nrgeo`. The `res` object is also a list--but a list of `igraph.vs` objects. The `igraph.vs` object is an `igraph` specific object known as a vertex sequence. Base R functions won't know what to do with it. So we use the `as_id` function to convert an `igraph.vs` object to a vector of ids.

Since `PathsE$res` is a list of `igraph.vs` objects, you need to iterate over the list and collapse it into a data frame. There are several ways to do this. Here is one:

```
set.seed(6857)
g <- sample_smallworld(1, 100, 5, 0.05) #Building a random graph
sp <- all_shortest_paths(g, 5, 70)
mat <- sapply(sp$res, as_ids) 
#sapply iterates the function as_ids over all elements in the list sp$res and collapses it into a matrix
```

This produces a matrix, but notice that it is the transpose of what you want:

```
> mat
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    5    5    5    5
[2,]  100    4  100    1
[3,]   95   65   65   75
[4,]   70   70   70   70
```

So, transpose it and convert to a data frame:

```
> df <- as.data.frame(t(mat))
  V1  V2 V3 V4
1  5 100 95 70
2  5   4 65 70
3  5 100 65 70
4  5   1 75 70
```

Which we can do in a single line of code:

```
set.seed(6857)
g <- sample_smallworld(1, 100, 5, 0.05)
sp <- all_shortest_paths(g, 5, 70)
df <- as.dataframe(t(sapply(sp$res, as_ids)))
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  That worked (and clarified a lot!)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, that's simple:

```
data.frame <- get.data.frame(g, what= c("vertices", "edges", "both") )
```

Be aware to choosing among the "what" options.

You also can save it in a .csv format using this script:

```
write.csv(data.frame, "data.frame.csv")
```

Comment: this only works for a graph object, not a vector of shortest path igraph.vs objects