# Converting a list of igraph.vs objects into a data frame (from all_simple_paths)

Tags: r, dataframe, igraph

So, this is a question extremely similar to one asked here: [Turning an igraph.vs into a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45068457/turning-an-igraph-vs-into-a-data-frame) however, I've had issues in applying the solution from that question to my own situation.

Similarly to the individual in that question, I have used the R `igraph` function `all_simple_paths()` to create a list of `igraph.vs` objects.

Then there is the added complexity that I have added further paths onto this list in the following manner:

```
for (i in 1:length(starts)){

  smple_path_n = all_simple_paths(info_igraph,
                                starts,
                                to = end)

  all_paths = c(all_paths, smple_path_n)

}
```

So I am combining the lists into one overall, larger list. This list of objects looks like this:

```
[[1]]
+ 3/? vertices, named, from 31c3f54 (deleted):
[1] hsa:1147 hsa:4790 hsa:6348

[[2]]
+ 3/? vertices, named, from d0aa080 (deleted):
[1] hsa:1147 hsa:4790 hsa:6348

[[3]]
+ 3/? vertices, named, from 60b5da5 (deleted):
[1] hsa:1326 hsa:4790 hsa:6348
```

The issue I am having now is that I want to convert these objects into a dataframe or matrix that looks something like this:

```
         hsa:1147 hsa:1326 hsa:4790 hsa:6348                
Pathway1    1    0    1    1
Pathway2    1    0    1    1 
Pathway3    0    1    1    1
```

All of this is quite similar to the question linked at the start here, but for whatever reason the `all_simple_paths()` function output does not seem to behave in the same way as the `all_shortest_paths()` function. So the proposed solution in the question does not appear to work for me.

When using `as_ids` on either the original lists (or on the combined overall list) I get the following error:

```
Error in UseMethod("as_ids") : 
no applicable method for 'as_ids' applied to an object of class "list"
```

Similarly the list does not appear to have any "columns" as when trying to divide it up with `all_paths$` there do not appear to be any sub-lists.

I don't really have any idea where to go from here as I don't really have enough experience with these objects to figure out what the issue might be (or even whether this isn't actually doable because of the way the function I'm using works). Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, in case anyone else does investigate a similar issue to this:

My issue was that you cannot apply the `as_ids` function to any group of simple pathways and it can only be applied to one at a time. This seems obvious in hindsight, but is somewhat frustrating given that it means it cannot be applied directly to a list of `igraph.vs` objects, which is exactly what the `all_simple_paths()` function returns.

My solution feels fairly inelegant, using a for loop, but appears to work:

```
dir_paths_part = list()

for (nsmples in 1:length(smple_path_n)){

  curr_smple = as_ids(smple_path_n[[nsmples]])

  dir_paths_part[[nsmples]] = curr_smple

}
```

Essentially I needed to apply the `as_ids` function to each element of the list individually and put them back into a new list.